# Angular 2 access base href

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a code in my solution which gets baseHref of an app

```
constructor( private router: Router) {
    let baseHref = this.router._location._baseHref;
```

You could see what I am getting it via private properties. Is there other way to get base url? aka the url before router added it's parts?

I am using angular2 rc4

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a duplicate: The "baseHref" is not necessarily the same as the current page's location.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `Location` class has `prepareExternalUrl()` that takes base href into account.

You can also try to inject `constructor(@Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) href:string)`

It seems `APP_BASE_HREF` can't be injected anymore without explicitly providing it.

**`PlatformLocation`** provides more details about the URL:

```ts
  import {PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';

  constructor(platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
    console.log((platformLocation as any).location);
    console.log((platformLocation as any).location.href);
    console.log((platformLocation as any).location.origin);
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/M9e4mco7PF8nc1CHs3aq?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome! location.prepareExternalUrl("")  just made my day a little bit better.

Comment: Quoting the docs though: "This class should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use Location"

Comment: @AmrMostafa what docs, what class?

Comment: This: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PlatformLocation-class.html

Comment: @AmrMostafa thanks for the hint. It doesn't seem to provide the same values though.

Comment: You welcome, and sadly yes, it doesn't. I only meant to say that direct use of PlatformLocation is discouraged.

Comment: I saw that, but `Location` doesn't provide that information.

Comment: "Property 'location' does not exist on type 'PlatformLocation'."

Comment: It's actually an instance of `BrowserPlatformLocation` which is not public but it has the `location` property. You can use `as any` to call it anyway without getting a static warning.

Comment: base href is than: 
`(this.platformLocation as any).location.pathname`

Comment: It's way better and safer to use `location.prepareExternalUrl("")` as @SimeonGrigorovich suggested.

Comment: As @AmrMostafa notes, the Angular documentation notes that application developers shouldn't access `PlatformLocation` directly. For more details and alternatives, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60705771/245602).

Comment: `APP_BASE_HREF` can be injected, you just need to add a access modifier:

`@Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private href: string`