# Angular routing dynamically display vanity route prefix

Tags: angular

I have a multi-tenant application, being segmented into multiple "Portals"

On app load we reach out to the db and match the url to find which portal we're supposed to be. So `http://www.mywebsite.com/customerA` sets some innards for the app.

```
const portal: Portal = await this.templateService.addressLookup(url);
```

We then have a default route per portal, which I'm trying to route to on load via

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(portal.routeTo, { skipLocationChange: true });
```

This works great, taking me to the new route.

What I want to accomplish is instead of naving to `http://www.mywebsite.com/route` I want the user to see `http://www.mywebsite.com/customerA/route` in the URL bar, but have that resolve to the route in the app as `http://www.mywebsite.com/route`

-- I think I can just manually set the url but I'm not sure how to handle this

To expound on how it's setup:

1) User goes to `http://www.mywebsite.com/customerA`, on app load that hits the database and says "okay you're customerA, go to default route /defaultRoute".

2) We set an internal context that saves portalId to drive some functionality, and include with all API calls.

3) Now I want to route to `http://www.mywebsite.com/customerA/defaultRoute`, but have angular router actually resolve it as just /defaultRoute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that what you need is [Base URL](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). It's a URL that you usually set the `<base>` tag inside HTML's `<head>` and it acts like a origin path for all relative links in the app.

Put this function in your index.html, so it'll run on each app start (approach taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084260/2313004), just add your own logic to determine the base URL according to the URL in the address bar):

```
<base href="/">
<script>
  (function() {
    window['_app_base'] = //your logic to determine a base from the current URL;
  })();
</script>
```

afterwards, in your App.module, let Angular know about it (attention to providers):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, Location } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './';
import { getBaseLocation } from './shared/common-functions.util';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useValue: window['_app_base'] || '/'
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If somewhere in your app you'll need to get it, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39287458/2313004):

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'; 

...

constructor(@Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private baseHref:string) {
  console.log(this.baseHref);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that'll work? I don't see how I can get that into my solution... I want to manually set the base href after load and an ngOnInit so I can ping the db for what portal we're on. I expanded my question with more specifics of how it's setup in my situation.

Comment: sorry @grreeenn once I set base href manually, it's almost behaving exaaactly how I want so this might work. But how can I dynamically set the base href after the app has loaded?

Comment: @JoshuaOhana I've edited my answer to be more intuitive. You're also welcome to go through links that I've provided, you'll find more info there :) this is solution by sharpmachine, I've used it and checked that it works.

Comment: Hey grreeenn I might be super confused. I want to SET base href I don't care about reading it so much. I see your way to read it and that's great, but I'm having issues setting it from within AppComponent

Comment: @JoshuaOhana did you put the change function into your index.html as described in the first code block?

Comment: I'm not sure that can work. I need the app already loaded and to make an api call, THEN set the base href. It's not based only on the url, I need to hit the api first to determine what the base href should be. I'm using now the providers APP_BASE_HREF with a factory to provide, but I can't make it work async

Comment: I made a new question that's more directed at the issue I"m having, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572834/change-base-href-after-angular-app-has-loaded