# How to pass variable from Express.js to Angular11 universal SSR

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Quick question, how we can pass to angular-universal HTML components or to the main app index.html variables from expressjs, like available from expressjs to ejs or pug?

```
        app.get('*', (req, res) => {
          res.render('index', { req, messsage: 'This is your message' });
        }
```

Ejs can get variable from expressjs like this:

```
    <h1><%= message %></h1>
```

Pug can get variable from expressjs like this:

```
 h1= message
```

We need to display a message from expressjs when the pages load or reloads into the ***view-source*** not in the shadow dom or DOM or as "inspect" on chrome. Must be on the ***view-source*** in the render HTML source file.

We using angular 11 SSR universal with expressjs.

Any ideas or is impossible?

Answer (score 8):

You can provide values from the server and use them in your components/services

**server.ts**

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.render('index', { req, res,  providers: [{ provide: 'message', useValue: 'This is your message' }] })
```

**component.ts**

```
import {Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {isPlatformBrowser} from "@angular/common";
import {TransferState, makeStateKey} from '@angular/platform-browser';

//Message here is optional because it is only provided in SSR mode

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
@Optional() @Inject('message') public message: string,
 private readonly transferState: TransferState)
{         
    const storeKey = makeStateKey<string>('messageKey');
    if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))//get message from transferState if browser side
    {
        this.message = this.transferState.get(storeKey, 'defaultMessageValue');
    }
    else //server side: get provided message and store in in transfer state
    {
        this.transferState.set(storeKey, this.message);
    }
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="message">Message from server : {{message}} </div>
```

With that code, your message will appear in the html rendered by the server (which you can see using view source).

Thanks to transfer state, the message is also available client side

**Edit** I added instructions so that the message is still available client side

Comment: How then we keep the value on the client-side, because is overwritten? as undefined. I need to keep the message in both areas

Comment: Then you can add it to transfer state

Comment: @jcdsr I added additional instructions since you obviously got stuck

Comment: actually, I was pretty stuck, thanks. on variable const storeKey is makeStateKey not makeCacheKey?

Comment: as well I'm getting, 
Error: src/app/app.component.html:23:13 - error TS2445: Property 'message' is protected and only accessible within class 'AppComponent' and its subclasses.

Comment: as well the value is not been rendered on the view-source, the value printed is the 'messageKey' - however shows perfect on the dom

Comment: @jcdsr I fixed the code (`public` message, using `makeStateKey`).

Comment: Still not working at 100% is not rendering properly when the page reload