# How to get an absolute Url by a route name in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In my Angualar 2 (final) application I need often to create a full (absolute) Url by a route name (like '/products'), e.g. to provide a permalink to a specific page or to open a page from a component in another tab/window.

Is any Angular 2 API, which allow to get an absolute Url by a route name? If no, is some known woraround for, e.g. using javascript?

I've tried location or PathLocationStrategy (e.g. prepareExternalUrl), but the method returns '/products' instead of e.g. http://localhost/products

Comment: Did you try using `window.location.host` concatenated with the return of `prepareExternalUrl`? Why do you need it? `routerLink` isn't enough?

Comment: The window.location.host does not contains a full base Url, e.g. for http://localhost.8000/virt_sites/virt_dir/test.html we expect "http://localhost.8000/virt_sites/virt_dir" instead of "http://localhost.8000". I need to open a project page in the new window from the component (not from the view!) using e.g. the window.open(absoluteUrl, '_blank'). Is it possible with routerLink? I think no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I've found for now

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
[...]

constructor(private _router: Router) { }

  redirectNewWindow() {    
  const internalUrl = '/products';

  // Resolve the base url as the full absolute url subtract the relative url.
  var currentAbsoluteUrl = window.location.href;
  var currentRelativeUrl = this._router.url;
  var index = currentAbsoluteUrl.indexOf(currentRelativeUrl);
  var baseUrl = currentAbsoluteUrl.substring(0, index);

  // Concatenate the urls to construct the desired absolute url.
  window.open(baseUrl + internalUrl, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: @vinagreti's answer should be accepted as it does not rely on window.location, and is therefore testable

Comment: This answer is only one which works when we use # (hash) in angular url's +1

Answer (score 5):

You can use `PlatformLocation` to get the base_url, then you can concatenate with the return of `prepareExternalUrl`:

```
    import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';

    export class MyComponent {
        constructor(
            private platformLocation: PlatformLocation
        ){
            this.logAppStart(platformLocation);
        }

        private logAppStart(platformLocation: any){ // CHANGED THE TYPE TO ANY TO BE ABLE TO ACCESS THE LOCATION PROPERTY
            console.log(platformLocation.location); // HERE YOU FIND WHAT YOU NEED
        }
    }
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485171/angular-2-access-base-href)

Comment: PlatformLocation.location returns a wrong information, e.g. for "http://localhost:20623/welcome" returns the same string instead of the base url "http://localhost:20623". In my answer I could reolve the correct base url, but not directly with angular 2 component.

Comment: Seems it's `platformLocation.origin`, not `platformLocation.location`

Comment: what about hash # urls ?

Comment: I combined this answer with the one from @SamanMahamadi to build the route I wanted, I didn't have a need for # urls though (and avoiding the need for window.location).

Comment: Downvoting this. Because, from the Angular docs for `PlatformLocation`:
> This class should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use Location.

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

[...]

constructor(private router: Router) { 
  let absoluteUrl = window.location.origin + this.router.createUrlTree(['/products']);
}
```

Comment: you should add more details

Comment: you might consider window.location.origin or window.origin. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451493/what-is-window-origin

Comment: not works when you have routes whith hash # (e.g https//mysite.com/#/users)

Comment: This doesn't work when you go from a base url such as `sharedserver.com/my-app/login` and the angular url is just `/login`, it will return `sharedserver.com/login`