# What is window.origin?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

What is `window.origin`? It doesn't seem to be documented in [the usual place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/origin).

It looks like it might be very similar to `window.location.origin` - for example, here on Stack Overflow, both return

> ```
> https://stackoverflow.com
> ```

But inside an `iframe`, they're different:

```js
console.log(window.location.origin);
console.log(window.origin);
```

> ```
> https://stacksnippets.net
> null
> ```

The embedded snippet is inside an `iframe` *without* `allow-same-origin`. If you change the iframe, for example, if you edit Stack Overflow's HTML and manually add the attribute:

```
<iframe name="313b857b-943a-7ffd-4663-3d9060cf4cb6" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-modals allow-scripts" class="snippet-box-edit" frameborder="0" style="">
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and then run the snippet, you get:

> ```
> https://stacksnippets.net
> https://stacksnippets.net
> ```

The same sort of behavior is exhibited on other sites with `<iframe>`s.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=window.origin) does not appear to have any authoritative links on the subject. Searching for the [exact phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22window.origin%22+javascript) + Javascript gives many results related to `iframe`s and `postMessage`, but no precise description of what `window.origin` *actually is*.

Calling `postMessage` from a child `iframe` appears to result in the parent window receiving a message with the `origin` property matching the `window.origin` of the child frame - without `allow-same-origin`, it's `null`, otherwise it looks like it's the same as the `window.location.origin` of the child.

The above is what I *think* I've figured out from guessing-and-checking, but I'm nowhere near certain. I'd appreciate a confirmation/explanation, preferably with a link to an authoritative source.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/origin

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/origin

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I didn't think to search for `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.origin`

Comment: so I get 50 rep? ;)

Comment: @mplungjan Sure! Relevant info looks to be [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-origin) and [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#sandboxed-origin-browsing-context-flag) (see **allow-same-origin** on the same page for why it was affecting the iframe), a "unique opaque origin" -> `'null'` is set under various conditions, otherwise a tuple origin (like `window.location.origin`) is assigned.

Comment: Note that in the top window context, `window.origin` will return `undefined` on older browsers like IE11, Edge 17 and Safari 10, while `window.location.origin` will return the correct origin. Newer browsers seem to support both.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[WindowOrWorkerGlobal.origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/origin) returns the origin of the environment, [Location.origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/origin) returns the origin of the URL of the environment.

Unfortunately Stack-Snippets null-origined frames will make for a confusing example...

At the risk of paraphrasing [the specs themselves](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-origin-dev),  let's say we are on `https://example.com` and from there, we create a new <iframe> element without an `src` attribute:

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe")
frame.onload = function() {
  var frameWin = frame.contentWindow;
  console.log(frameWin.location.href); // "about:blank"
  console.log(frameWin.location.origin) // "null"
  console.log(frameWin.origin) // "https://example.com"
}
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/ofbujxwg/)

The `location` of our `frameWin` is `"about:blank"` and its `location.origin` is `"null"`, because `"about:blank"` is an [opaque origin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#concept-origin-opaque).

However, the frame's Window `frameWin` got its own `origin` set to the one of the parent Window (`"https://example.com"`) which was set when `frameWin`'s *browsing context* got initialized.

---

If you wish a little diving into the specs here are the relevant steps for the previous example:

- At `frame` creation:
  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-iframe-element:about:blank

> If the element has no `src` attribute specified, or its value is the empty string, let `url` be the URL "about:blank".

- When creating a new  *browsing context* for `frame`
  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#creating-browsing-contexts:about:blank

> If invocationOrigin is not null, and url is about:blank, then return invocationOrigin.

So here it has been determined that `origin` of the new *browsing context* is `invocationOrigin`, i.e the `origin` of the *browsing context* that did create `frame`, while `url`, used by `location`, is `"about:blank"`.

---

Now the case of StackSnippets sandboxed frames is a bit particular in that they do have an `src` and thus a [tuple-origin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#concept-origin-tuple) *url*, but since their `sandbox` attribute makes their *origin* opaque, they'll behave at the inverse of what is exposed in the previous example, making `self.origin` return `"null"` and `location` return the iframe's `src`'s URL.

Comment: Interesting answer, I'm trying to understand a few conception of html spec related with Realms. Could you look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72163986/difference-between-current-realm-and-incumbent-realm)?

Answer (score 6):

Quite an interesting question!

We can start with some investigation - let's see the output from `window`

```js
console.log(window)
```

That file is quite big... The Window interface represents a window containing a DOM document; the document property points to the DOM document loaded in that window and describes several features common to the Window and WorkerGlobalScope.

[more details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope)

But then you want to see a very particular property `window.origin`.

**window.origin**
That one is quite boring for stack overflow (code snippet) as you saw, the json obj returned for window brings:

```
"origin": "null"
```

This response is the way the window tell us that the origin is not the same and that we were not allowed the same-origin for that window. Quite common effect for `iframe` as you deducted yourself!

You also saw that the `window.location` is less boring... as it contains some more data to it as the Location interface represents the location (URL) of the object it is linked to and the cool thing is that any changes done on it are reflected on the object it relates to. So that is why we don't get a null in here.

**window.location...**

```
"location": {
    "ancestorOrigins": {
        "0": "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "length": 1,
        "item": function item() {
            [native code
            ]
        },
        "contains": function contains() {
            [native code
            ]
        }
    },
    "origin": "https://stacksnippets.net",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not documented because both are the same with little difference,
It most cases it doesn't really matter which option you choose to use. There are, however, a few instances where one is preferred over the other, such as:

1. same-origin policy conflicts if setting a new URL in an iframe or another window that is already of a different origin from the current window (e.g an iframe has a different domain than the document it is loaded in and you want to change the URL of the iframe) would use window. location to set the new URL. This is because location.href is read-only when called from a different origin (domain).
2. if using use strictly in your JavaScript may cause an exception if using window. location since you are essentially assigning a string to an object, so here it would be best to use the full window.location.href.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location) for reference.

Comment: It *is* documented in the links in the comments - if you describe and reference the official specification that describes the behavior (see my comment - "unique opaque origin" is an important phrase), I'll award a bounty :)

Answer (score 4):

**Location describes the URL of the current page. It is available through the window. location property.**

```
<a id='foo' href='#bar'>Go to #bar</a>


<div style='height: 1000px'></div>


<a id='bar' href='#foo'>Go to #foo</a>
<script>
  var printHash = function() {




    console.log("'" + window.location.hash + "'");

  };
  // Print initial hash
  printHash();
  window.onhashchange = printHash;
</script>`enter code here`
```

More info:
Internet Explorer does not have access to window.location.origin, which is a bummer because it is a pretty handy variable to have, but we can make it work with a fairly straight forward check because we access .origin;

```
if (!window.location.origin) {
  window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
}
```