# How to get base url in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

My current url is http://localhost:4200/test/dashboard.

I want to print base url i.e http://localhost:4200 using angular 5 features.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222845/how-to-get-domain-name-for-service-in-angular2

Comment: try out `document.baseURI`. may it helps to you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

console.log(location);

console.log(location.href);

to get base url : `console.log(location.origin);`

Answer (score 79):

The other answers here cover quite a range of options:

- `location`
- `window.location`
- `document.location`
- `DOCUMENT` / `Document`
- `Location`
- `LocationStrategy`
- `PlatformLocation`

**TLDR;** for simple situations the globally available DOM `location` may be enough for your needs. However, you probably really want an Angular `Location` instance. And, in certain circumstances, `LocationStrategy` may also be useful.

You can access the DOM `location` directly without needing to import anything:

```
foo(): void {
  console.log(location.origin);
  console.log(location.href);
  console.log(location.pathname);
}
```

If you want to use the Angular `Location` and `LocationStrategy` then you have to pull them in like so:

```
import { Location, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location, private locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) { }

foo(): void {
  console.log(this.location.path());
  console.log(this.location.prepareExternalUrl('/'));
  console.log(this.locationStrategy.getBaseHref());
}
```

You can use `prepareExternalUrl` to e.g. construct URLs that refer to assets:

```
const url = this.location.prepareExternalUrl('assets/svg/icons.svg');
```

If you're serving everything out from directly under `/`, there may not seem to be much point using the Angular `Location` but if you've set your application's base href to be something other than `/` or if you're doing more complicated things with paths then Angular `Location` will help you work with this kind of thing correctly.

If `prepareExternalUrl` doesn't seem to be picking up your base href, see the notes about this at the end of this answer.

In some examples, you'll see it stated that you have to configure `APP_BASE_HREF` in order for things to pick up your base href. This is not the case anymore, see the end of this answer for more on this.

Note: by default Angular uses the location strategy `PathLocationStrategy` but if you've changed things to use `HashLocationStrategy` then `prepareExternalUrl` and other functions will not work the same way. However, if you're using `HashLocationStrategy` you probably know what you're doing, so I won't go into this here.

### The full details

Let's have a look in turn at each of the entities listed above.

**1.** `location`, `window.location` and `document.location` are of type `Location`, come directly from the DOM and are available as global variables, i.e. you don't have to import or inject them in any way.

These are all ways of getting at the same thing. `location` and `window.location` are literally the same thing (`window` can be referred to explicitly but it is also the implicit global `this`). `location` and `document.location` are *essentially* the same thing, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2430936/245602) for more details on this.

You can find the MDN documentation for `Location` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

So if the DOM `Location` is all that you want, I would just use `location`. Some people like to be explicit that they're accessing the `window` object and prefer to use `window.location`. The `location` field of `document` has a confusing history and seems to be the least popular way to access a DOM `Location` instance.

**2.** Elsewhere, you can see people using the Angular dependency injection token `DOCUMENT` like so:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document)
```

Then you can access `this.document.location`. Again, this is simply a DOM `Location` instance, so if this is what you want, why bother injecting it when you can access it directly as `location`? The `this.document` and the globally available `document` mentioned above are both of type `Document` and, in a browser context, they are the same thing. So the only reason you'd inject it is if you're working in a non-browser context.

You can find the Angular documentation for `DOCUMENT` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT) and the MDN documentation for `Document` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document).

**3.** Finally three Angular entities - [`Location`](https://angular.io/api/common/Location), [`LocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy) and [`PlatformLocation`](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation).

Confusingly, Angular has used the same name for their location type (i.e. `Location`) as the type of `location` etc. up above. The DOM `Location` is available globally and doesn't need to be imported, the Angular `Location` needs to be imported from `@angular/common`.

The Angular entities `Location`, `LocationStrategy` and `LocationStrategy` are layered on top of each other, a `Location` contains a `LocationStrategy` and a `LocationStrategy` in turn contains a `PlatformLocation`. None of them directly exposes the contained entity, i.e. you can't get to the `LocationStrategy` via the `Location` API nor to the `PlatformLocation` via the `LocationStrategy`.

You'll see many older examples directly accessing `PlatformLocation` but as its [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation) makes clear, this "class should **not** be used directly by an application developer."

#### Conclusions

So we started with a confusing array of entities but in the end, it really just boils down to choosing between the DOM provided global `location` object and the Angular provided `Location` object. Under certain circumstances, `LocationStrategy` may also be of interest.

### Code

But if you want more insight, why not try out the following code that pulls in every one of the entities that have been mentioned. Look at the console output to see what each entity provides and just experiment with the APIs of each. For simplicity just add this code to one of your existing components:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT, Location, LocationStrategy, PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';

// Normally, you should not access PlatformLocation directly, it's just included here for completeness.
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, private location: Location, private locationStrategy: LocationStrategy, private plaformLocation: PlatformLocation) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    // These are just different ways to get the same thing, so if this
    // is what want, you might as well use plain location directly.
    console.log('DOM location', location)
    console.log('DOM window.location', window.location)
    console.log('DOM document.location', document.location)
    console.log('Injected document.location', this.document.location)

    // These are layered on top of each other. A Location contains a
    // LocationStrategy and a LocationStrategy contains a PlatformLocation.
    // Note that this.location, used here, is a different thing to plain location above.
    console.log('location', this.location)
    console.log('locationStrategy', this.locationStrategy)
    console.log('platformLocation', this.plaformLocation) // PlatformLocation "should not be used directly by an application developer."
}
```

Open your app in a browser and look at the console output in developer tools and see if you find what you're looking for.

Note: things become stale quickly in the Angular world - the above all worked fine with Angular 9.

### Base href and `Location`

If you have a simple application with no routes and you've set the base href to something other than `/` then you may find that functions like `prepareExternalUrl` fail to take the base href into account. This happens if you haven't included a `RouterModule` in the `imports` section of your `app.module.ts`. For whatever reason, the `LocationStrategy` and `PlatformLocation`, that underly `Location`, are only properly configured if a `RouterModule` is imported. To get around this, just add the following:

```
imports: [
  ...
  RouterModule.forRoot([]),
  ...
]
```

Even though you've specified no routes, i.e. passed in `[]`, this will properly configure things to take your base href into account.

### `APP_BASE_HREF`, `PlatformLocation` and `Location`

In some examples, you'll see it stated that you have to explicitly configure `APP_BASE_HREF` in order for things to pick up your base href. E.g. like so in `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [{
  provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
  useFactory: (pl: PlatformLocation) => pl.getBaseHrefFromDOM(),
  deps: [PlatformLocation]
}]
```

This *may* have been necessary at some stage but the current `PathLocationStrategy` code does this for you automatically, i.e. if you don't set `APP_BASE_HREF` then it will itself retrieve the base href value using the `getBaseHrefFromDOM()` method of `PathLocationStrategy`. You can see this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/10.0.1/packages/common/src/location/location_strategy.ts#L107) in the `constructor` logic of `PathLocationStrategy`.

Comment: Best explanation and summary about the whole base href topic I've read so far.Solves many issues for me. Thx a lot for it.

Comment: I gave you thumbs up.  how to implement the same thing in SSR

Comment: Great description of how to use Location. Thank you.

Answer (score 50):

No need for angular specific features, `window.location.origin` will do it for you.

Comment: This answer is probably perfect for most situations. However, if you've set your base href to something other than `/` or you need support for more complicated situations, there are a whole load of additional options. For details on these, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60705771/245602).

Answer (score 17):

This doesn't work for me (Angular 7):

```
this.location.path.name
```

But I found that it's possible to get it from document:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    const origin = this.document.location.origin;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

PlatformLocation provides more details about the URL:

```
import {PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';

 constructor(platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
  console.log((platformLocation as any).location);
  console.log((platformLocation as any).location.href);
  console.log((platformLocation as any).location.origin);
}
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of using PlatformLocation. This would break if Angular wasn't running in a browser.

Comment: The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation) for `PlatformLocation` says it "should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use `Location`." See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60705771/245602) for `Location` and a whole range of alternatives.

Answer (score 12):

```js
import { DOCUMENT, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UrlService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document,
    private readonly locationStrategy: LocationStrategy,
  ) {}

  getBaseUrl(): string {
    return this.document.location.origin + this.locationStrategy.getBaseHref();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used location from **Rotemya**'s answer like this

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(public location: Location) { }
```

But this.location.origin didn't work for me. So I have used this.location.path.name

```
 ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.location.path.name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the base url from the base tag in `index.html`, because sometimes the page is hosted in a sub directory, this should include the sub directory as part of the base url.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        <base href="./">
        <!-- ... -->
    <head>
    <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

This will get that base element and get the `baseURI` from it:

```
let base = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0]?.baseURI ?? location.origin;
```

Here the function to get the path from the base:

```
private getUriPath(): string {
    let base = document.getElementsByTagName('base');
    if (base.length > 0) {
        let baseURI = base[0].baseURI;
        let pathname = window.location.href.replace(baseURI, '');
        let parametersIndex = pathname.indexOf('?');
        if (parametersIndex > -1) {
            pathname = pathname.substring(0, parametersIndex);
        }
        return pathname;
    }
    return window.location.pathname;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can Try (Can Get all Detail of current location)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
 selector: 'some-component',
 templateUrl: './component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./component.scss']
})

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(location: Location) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.location._platformStrategy._platformLocation.location);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can import 'Location' from the 'common' package:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common'; // <--- Here
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: './component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.scss']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(location: Location) {}

  ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.location.origin);  // <--- Use Here
  }

}
```

Comment: There is no 'origin' in this location object

Comment: The property origin does not exist for this class.