# Angular server-side rendering (SSR) | How to get domain name

Tags: angular

My web application is accessible through multiple domains (`example.com` `example.org` `example.net`).

**Question:** How can I access the domain of the current route?

**Please note:**
I use SSR (server side rendering), answer can therefore not include `window` or any other browser object.

**Expected result:**
If application is accessed via `example.org` and current route is `www.example.org/frontpage`

```
const domain = await someFunction()
console.log(domain);
// example.org
```

Comment: does that work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984268/how-to-get-base-url-in-angular-5

Comment: No, all answers would not work on a server environment (my application is rendered on the server (SSR))

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I get `x-forwarded-host` from the request this way:

In **server.ts**:

```js
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const xForwardedHost = req.headers['x-forwarded-host'];
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
      { provide: 'X_FORWARDED_HOST', useValue: xForwardedHost },
    ] });
  });
```

Then inject `'X_FORWARDED_HOST'` where you need it, for instance:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject('X_FORWARDED_HOST') private host: any,

  ) {
    console.log('My host is',host);
  }
}
```

Since `'X_FORWARDED_HOST'` was defined only in **server.ts**, it only exists in the server. In the browser it will be null, thats why you should use the `@Optional()` decorator, otherwise you are going to get an error.

Comment: With ng serve, in my local, i'm getting null. The same deployed in azure static websites :(