# Angular 6: Get base href

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would like to get  in angular 6 component.
I managed it by: [PlatformLocation#getBaseHrefFromDOM](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation).

But this api should not be used by developers. Is there any other way to get /CTX-ROOT/assets/tiny-editor/langs/cs.js in runtime?

```
  constructor(
    private zone: NgZone,
    private platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    var baseHref = this.platformLocation.getBaseHrefFromDOM();
    Observable.fromPromise(tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      entity_encoding: "raw",
      menubar: false,
      branding: false,
      elementpath: true,
      language_url: baseHref + '/assets/tiny-editor/langs/cs.js',
```

Comment: Leave it as it is. You could alternatively select base element by yourself using DOM API but that does not make any difference.

Comment: please see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485171/angular-2-access-base-href

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `prepareExternalUrl` method from the `Location` service ([doc](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#prepareExternalUrl))

```
import {Location} from "@angular/common";

//...
constructor(
    private zone: NgZone,
    private location: Location) {
}


public ngAfterViewInit() {
    Observable.fromPromise(tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      entity_encoding: "raw",
      menubar: false,
      branding: false,
      elementpath: true,
      language_url: this.location.prepareExternalUrl('assets/tiny-editor/langs/cs.js')
```

**Edit**: I assume this only works when using `PathLocationStrategy`

> This method will also add a hash if HashLocationStrategy is used, or the APP_BASE_HREF if the PathLocationStrategy is in use.

Comment: but this returns "#/assets/tiny-editor/langs/cs.js" (<base href="/xxx/">)

Comment: @PetrPrikryl You are using PathLocationStrategy for your routing, right?

Comment: nope, do I have to?     RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})

Comment: OK, i will switch to path location strategy. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

How about you use native JS for it? window.location will give the Location object. window.location.origin will give you the base href.

Comment: this returns window.location.origin
"http://localhost:3000" instead of 
"http://localhost:3000/xxx/"

Comment: window.location gives an object where there are a number of information. You could use "origin" and "pathname" to get any part of url you want.